# Error when submitting Membership renewal

Tags: civimember, contribution-page, recaptcha

I have it turned on to have recaptcha on the anonymous registration pages, and it doesn't show on the renewal page once logged in, like it is supposed to. When I actually try to submit a renewal, it get a console error of

```
recaptcha__en.js:247 Uncaught Error: No reCAPTCHA clients exist.
    at Array.<anonymous> (recaptcha__en.js:247)
    at Array.<anonymous> (recaptcha__en.js:13)
    at submit (civicrmStripe.b4942341a5b9c992b168cbcd8ee4b5fd.js:485)
    at HTMLInputElement.submitButtonClick (civicrmStripe.b4942341a5b9c992b168cbcd8ee4b5fd.js:403)
```

I tried to disable recaptcha on the site, even removing the API keys to even prevent the lookup, and I still get this same error. This started after the last 5.26 update, and continues on with the 5.27.0 update using Wordpress.

Edit: I discovered this only happens when I am using Stripe, it works fine when using PayPal. I would prefer to keep using Stripe, but I still haven't been able to isolate the issue.

Comment: have mentioned at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/ikabzc78ybbbzewjnkpa88htpr

Comment: Which version of the stripe extension please? There is a fix that will be in 6.4.2 for some reCaptcha issues: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/blob/6.4.2/docs/releasenotes.md